# Formulas for $f,g$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=a\cdot f(a,b)+b\cdot g(a,b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there formulas for functions 
$f,g:\mathbb N^2\to \mathbb N$ 
such that $\gcd(a,b)=a\cdot f(a,b)+b\cdot g(a,b)$ for all $a,b>0$?

Comment: They can be determined by the Euclid algorithm, but there should not be any "reasonable" formula.

Comment: @Cave Johnson: Ok, thanks!